# Why is negative bytes read as 65533 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I'm trying to transfer a file from my Java Servlet to a small HTML Web implementation.

I'm using a regular http ajax request to the servlet and the problem is that every byte sent from the Servlet that is outside the 0-127 range is being read on Javascript as 65533, thus creating bad files on the receiving end.

I've been doing the Ajax request on XHR, Jquery and AngularJS and got the same result every time.

Why is this happening ? What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Sound like an ecoding issue, is your Java Servlet sending an encoding.. This day an age, UTF-8 is pretty much the norm..

Comment: I have no custom header other than "Content-Disposition: attachment"

Comment: Ok, that might be your problem.. The default might be binary.. Try changing the content-type ->  `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: That didn't work, maybe I should change the Content Disposition as well ?

Comment: Just a thought, are we sure the file your transferring is UTF-8?  If it's windows it could easy be iso-8859-1, so maybe you could do `Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`

Answer (score 2):

*Your input stream is being read as **UTF-8**, so replace it with **ISO-8859-1***

UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can represent any character.

ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding that can represent the first 256 Unicode characters.

UTF-8 replaces certain characters outside a range with special 'Unicode replacement character' which in your case is **0xFFFD** (65533 in Hex).

Answer (score -1):

����N�ne�]_�'ǭT��n��>��q���Z�L�L2��By��z���4$����X�}�]ũ�<���
�~ϵW��5<�?}�Åo�t���`��b�oD2ɖ�7Lq!���In��`�58�>N�?�#����l�`���HA��d�A�J&RF�q���]*T]�P�u�F��ud'9���א�V��D�����5C�����̞�<�aIz6܍X�p�P����d���O��F�R�ZXXX�Wi|��������Q)ew��8��:5�������`�`������yII����zz��:V/�eP�7�IU�=���?J['������b!Gi�ba�Q^�!Gz����At�Le����x�X�e¨�o�!^�����eG&#0;%�O
o���$6��*�ײ�������1�������ܔ�V@kD�ʯH����E�� gԑ���QK7|�O3w*�0卖�!t'����&�/��[�u�Y�6���_�<�ݒ"m��?{�8�_���6{�%��&Dݓ������l�sb
���¢d],���k��?ؿ��&#0;z8�����0�k������Xi��:)�i�v�UׅY�h��>f���?�;�Z���NPE�g�T�`��>��jSl���S�]TpP�G=L0�V�/��Of��L�γ"��m�/��I���-|X4J����G*���3�<Ա�Ya���;�1�`;r�[���[co��u�˾HK�r���<���X)��+c���@�IX �;$<�dD�9�

```
256
```

Comment: Please add a description what it mean.